# Webview not being seen as a mobile browser

Tags: android

In my webview I am going to http://www.nsopw.gov/Core/OffenderSearchCriteria.aspx
when this is done via the android browser it is seen as a mobile site.

But in my app in a webview it is seen as not a mobile browser therefore not being redirected to the mobile version.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.buttons);
    wb = new WebView(this);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    String[] loading = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_loading);

    Random r = new Random();
    int rN = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Sex_Offenders.this, loading[rN],
            "Loading...");

     final String urlToLoad ="http://www.nsopw.gov/Core/OffenderSearchCriteria.aspx";
    //final String urlToLoad = "http://m.familywatchdog.us/m_v2/msa.asp?es=&l=0&w=0&brtp=html&rstp=xlarge&imgtp=jpg&imgw=310&imgh=320";

    wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    if (Repeatables.isNetworkAvailable(context) == true) {
        wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        wb.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
    } else {
        wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        wb.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
        Repeatables.NoConnectionAlert(this);
    }
    setContentView(wb);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try forcing the user agent string yourself, as it appears that the webview user agent string is not identifying itself as a mobile browser. 
use

```
webview.getSettings.setUserAgentString(...)
```

You can google for the useragent string, I used

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

and it worked with the link you provided in your site and loaded the mobile version.

Comment: wb.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");