# How to open desktop site in webview in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need to open desktop site in android webview for that i have tried as below but it is not working.

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the perfect solution:

```
 private static final String DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";
 private static final String MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JOP24G) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30";

 //Choose Mobile/Desktop client.
 WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
 settings.setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USER_AGENT);
```

---

### UPDATE

The above MOBILE_USER_AGENT is no longer supported.
so use the given below user agent

```
private static final String MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Redmi 6 Pro Build/PKQ1.180917.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Not working it is opening every time mobile website not desktop website

Comment: i want to open desktop site in webview

Comment: what is your webview client which you are setting in webview ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setDesktopMode(true) from [this WebView subclass](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) or read how it's [implemented](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358). What is does is (a) set the user-agent not to include the words "mobile" or "Android" and (b) set the viewport to a larger width.

Comment: Already tried it but it only first time load desktop website when i open application next time that time it is displaying only mobile website.

Comment: refer to this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166228/android-webview-not-loading-mobile-site

Answer (score 1):

**For Mobile User-Agent**

`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JOP24G) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");`

**For Desktop site Agent**

`browser.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; diordnA 7.1.1; suxeN 6 Build/N6F26U; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.132 eliboM Safari/537.36");`

A lot of searches this code fine working on Android `webview`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me: refer to [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/6db5a76b781c636513282b9efed993e705db4570/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java#L358) as mentioned by @saurabh gutpa as well

```
public void setDesktopMode(final boolean enabled) {
    final WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();

    final String newUserAgent;

    if (enabled) {
        newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("Mobile", "eliboM").replace("Android", "diordnA");
    }
    else {
        newUserAgent = webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("eliboM", "Mobile").replace("diordnA", "Android");
    }

    webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(enabled);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(enabled);
}
```