# How to launch a Desktop site from my app?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm uploading a URL to `CustomTabs`. I want to enable pinch zoom in `CustomTabs`. By default it does not enable `zoom pinch`, but if you go to the menu and tap`Desktop Site`, enable pinch zoom.

I want to know that if there is a way to open `Desktop site` by default when the user launches a web URL from my app.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this answer... 
I've tried this and it works well

[How to open desktop site in webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931716/how-to-open-desktop-site-in-webview-in-android)

*You can set user agent for your webView programmatically*

In case something happens to the link, here's the answer for your question from that link:

```
private static final String DESKTOP_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36";
private static final String MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/JOP24G) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30";

//Choose Mobile/Desktop client.
WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USER_AGENT);
```